# how to subtract '2' from var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth + '';?

Tags: javascript

how can I subtract 2 from the clientWidth?
the var width must be (document.documentElement.clientWidth) - 2

```
var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth + '';
```

i suppose not like this:

```
var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth-2 + ''; ?
```

Thanks
AO

Comment: "*And when the answer that you want is in the question that you state.*" - Claudio Sanchez

Comment: Answer is in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth-2;
```

No need to add a string, unless you want the result to be a string.